# Using a Loop to animate items one at a time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a loop that animates three items one at a time. I keep getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined." What I think is happening is that for some reason the animation bit might be causing the loop to run all the way to three, and since bits[3] does not exist it keeps saying undefined.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("infoBits");
var d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var bits = d.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
  var opac = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    if (opac == 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      opac += 0.1;
      bits[i].style.opacity += 0.05;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#infoBits td {
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="infoBits" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Info Box 1</td>
    <td>Info Box 2</td>
    <td>Info Box 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yps4w6f4/

I would appreciate any advice or insight into how to make this work or better methods to use.

Comment: Where is `opac` declared in your code ?

Comment: And maybe im wrong but doesnt the for loop keep going and i isnt i anymore when setInterval triggers?

Comment: Don't use an HTML table unless you're representing tabular data. Use a CSS table, floats, inline-block, or flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the outer loop executed all the way through, creating 3 setIntervals and leaving i with a final value of 3. When the frame function is called, i is still referring to the outer i with a value of 3.

There are a couple of strategies you can use. Either create a closure to pass the value of i, or perhaps easier, use the bind function: setInterval(frame.bind({theBit:bits [i]}) and inside frame, this.theBit.style.opacity += 0.05;

The bind function will, at the time its evaluated in your outer loop, create a new function with the value of this set equal to whatever value the bind argument has at that instant, so it will create a different version of the frame function for every value of i.

Comment: I implemented the bind function into the JSfiddle, but I am not sure if I did it correctly. It does sounds like in theory this will end up being the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = document.getElementById("infoBits");
 var d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0]; 
var bits = d.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) { 
var pos = 0; 
//pass i as argument
var opac=0;
var id = setInterval(frame(i), 100);
 function frame(a){
 if (opac == 1) {
 clearInterval(id);
 } else { 
opac += 0.1; 
bits[a].style.opacity += 0.05; } 
}
 }
```

Youve got two problems:

1.Opac isnt set when you run opac===1 and opac+=0.001. So your browser will crash because he cannot increase a number that doesnt exist.

2.While the interval is waiting, i is increased, so this will lead to unexpected behaviour. So i fixed it through passing i to the function.

Comment: Please update explaination, without which, it wont be much useful @Jonas.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have variable mismatch going on. In my first iteration pos was the variable I used for the animation. I switched to opac to make it clearer for people trying to help me. I am not mistake won't declaring opac = 0; inside of frame() cause the interval to loop endlessly?

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding this. I am fairly new to javascript.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry my mistake